# How to stop showing a blank page when going to next fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

For what I did is first to create a tapBar (Activity). Then under Activity, I have first, second and third fragments. I am trying to move to next fragment from first fragment but I get a blank page (since it is not blue color which I set in xml). Any suggestions?

Activity

```
public class TabBar extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabbar);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

First fragment

```
public class First extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first, null);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Fragment fragment = new Next();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.hide(First.this);
                fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    return rootView;
}
```

Next Fragment

```
public class Next extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.next, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Next Fragment XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/avoscloud_blue">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set `viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);` .

Comment: As much i understand, you are trying to make activity with tabs right? Then why are you not using default tab view activity template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add [**`.add(R.id.`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.app.Fragment))

> FragmentTransaction add (int containerViewId, 
>                   Fragment fragment)

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                Next childFrag = new Next ();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_child_fragment, childFrag)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
            }
        });
```

Read [**`Nested Fragments`**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) for better information.

**Edit**

You should set **DEFAULT** tab

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(0); // 0 is FIRST
```

Create a **`FrameLayout`** in **`R.layout.first`**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_child_fragment"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
```

Comment: Um. May I know where should I add the frame_child_fragment id?

Comment: @PakHoCheung Kindly check my answer  or check https://why-android.com/2016/03/18/learn-about-nested-fragments/

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the help. I can move it to next fragment. Got one more question. So for a fragment that has next fragment, I need to use hide the FrameLayout onCreated and hide the FrameLayout when moving to next fragment?

Comment: Opps. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this method to change the `fragment`:

```
public void changeFragment() {
    Fragment fragment = new Next();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.your_layout_id, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tansaction.replace() this method work for new fragment if it will not work than make custom pager adapter and try again using it. and if you dont want to create pager adapter just add container layout in your xml and put fragment inside it and replace that fragment on button click